# How to enable automatic login after installing elementary OS Loki

Tags: settings, release-loki, greeter, user

I am trying to enable autologin but when I go to **System Settings** > **User Accounts** my account is listed as **(null)** and autologin cannot be enabled.

[image: (null) user account]

What should I do ?

Comment: I guess this might be a bug. Are there any non-ASCII characters in your username / login name?

Comment: no. there aren't any non asci characters in it

Answer (score 3):

You can try to do so using command line. Here's the [help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutoLogin). In particular you need to use,

`sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

and thereafter, add the following lines,

`[SeatDefaults]
autologin-user=<YOUR USERNAME>
autologin-user-timeout=0
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-session=unity-greeter`

This is slightly different than what's mentioned in help page since that's for older release.

Edit - Here's [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/51087).

Comment: Works but breaks the lock screen.

Answer (score 1):

I am on `Hera`  - Elementary 5.1.

Tried many ways. This is the only way working for me.

`/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

```
[seats:*]
autologin-guest=false
```

`/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01-xx.conf`

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=false
autologin-user=xx
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

`lightdm --show-config`

```
   [Seat:*]
G  greeter-session=false
A  user-session=pantheon
B  allow-guest=false
D  greeter-wrapper=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session
E  guest-wrapper=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session
F  xserver-command=X -core
G  autologin-user=xx
G  autologin-user-timeout=0
H  autologin-guest=false

   [LightDM]
C  backup-logs=false

Sources:
A  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/40-io.elementary.greeter.conf
B  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-disable-guest.conf
C  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-disable-log-backup.conf
D  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-greeter-wrapper.conf
E  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-guest-wrapper.conf
F  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf
G  /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01-xx.conf
H  /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```